# How to store multiple, variable, amounts of specification tables in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, json, database, database-design

I have a product database, and each product can have as many tables as needed for specifications and these specification tables themselves can have different numbers of columns depending on the product.

I'm just wondering how I would approach this when designing the database.

I'm thinking JSON as a data type would be the way to go but having never used it before I'm curious, and I'm wondering how I would store a variable amount of spec tables. Do I use a pivot table for example or could the json data type hold multiple entries?

Any pointers or advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to design the relation if many to many then you need to create third table

Comment: please give us examples about these products and specifications

Comment: Well an example would be a 'can of Beans', and an 'umbrella'. The Beans could have a specification table for weight and dimensions, one for ingredients, and yet another for calories and healthy eating. The Umbrella might have a specification table for weight and dimensions, and perhaps a specification table for it's waterproof rating or some such. The point is the specification tables, and their number of columns and titles etc, aren't necessarily known beforehand. That's why I'm assuming JSON is the way to go?

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/working-with-json-in-mysql found a pretty useful tutorial I'm working through now. I'm beginning to have second thoughts given how would I know how to iterate over them if they weren't explicitly named etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you need to create  two tables   on for products and another for specifications.

It seems to me there is many to many relationship between the products and specifications table, So one good idea is to create a third table which should has a product_id and specification_id as foreign keys in addition to it's primary key off course.

To simplify the issue I suggest to add a new column called specification_description which may be null or not depending on the product.

-- Table products

```
  CREATE TABLE  products 
 (
   product_id  Int  primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
   product_name   json 
 )
 ;
```

-- Table specifications

```
CREATE TABLE  specifications 
(
  specification_id  Int   PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  specification_type json,
  specification_desc json  
)
;
```

-- Table product_specification_table

```
  CREATE TABLE `product_specification_table 
  (
   product_specification_id  Int primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
   specification_id  Int,
   product_id  Int 
  )
 ;
```

-- Create foreign keys (relationships) section -------------------------------------------------

```
 ALTER TABLE  product_specification_table  ADD CONSTRAINT  Relationship1  FOREIGN KEY ( specification_id ) REFERENCES  specifications  ( specification_id ) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;


 ALTER TABLE  product_specification_table  ADD CONSTRAINT  Relationship2  FOREIGN KEY ( product_id ) REFERENCES  products  ( product_id ) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: please don't forget to mark or upvote my answer if it helps you.